# How to tell rpmbuild to use extracted folder instead of archive?

Tags: linux-kernel, rpmbuild

I installed a sources rpm for Linux kernel on Centos. And I need to make modifications to the kernel and build it. The kernel.spec file has the line that tells rpmbuild to get the sources to build from the archive file

```
Source0: linux-%{rpmversion}-%{pkgrelease}.tar.xz
```

The archive is in the typical location: ~/rpmbuild/SOURCES/linux-%{rpmversion}-%{pkgrelease}.tar.xz
I extracted the archive in the same directory, and that is ~/rpmbuild/SOURCES/linux-%{rpmversion}-%{pkgrelease}

How to tell rpmbuild to get the sources from the extracted version which has my changes and not from the archive?

I already tried the trivial solution to just remove ".tar.xz" extension, but that did not work:

```
error: File /root/rpmbuild/SOURCES/linux-3.10.0-957: Is a directory
```

Comment: Oh, no. It's done in different way. So, say, we have clean (after running something like _rpm -bp linux...-957_). Copy that folder completely under a name _linux...-957.orig_. Then, make changes and run _diff -ruN -p linux...-957.orig linux...-957_. This will give you a patch file, which you may save in the _$rpm/..._ (i forgot the folder, something like _SOURCES_ there). And edit the _*.spec_ file by adding __Patch:__ tag. A-ha, _$rpm_ in your case _/root/rpmbuild_. No need to be root to build, and it's actually dangerous.

Comment: Roughly https://cromwell-intl.com/open-source/rpm-patch.html but I'll try to find better.

Comment: Similar https://wiki.centos.org/HowTos/RebuildSRPM.

Comment: This seems very good and comprehensive: https://rpm-packaging-guide.github.io